Kunen recursive definition of $\Vdash^*$ in the $\exists$-case.
Stupid question: In Kunens "Set Theory An Introduction to Independence Proofs", VII, $\S3$, definition 3.3,(e), we are given the following: $$p \Vdash^* \exists x\ \phi(x,\tau_1,\ldots,\tau_n) \leftrightarrow ``\{r: \exists \sigma \in \mathbf{V}^{\mathbb{P}}(r \Vdash^* \phi(\sigma,\tau_1,\ldots,\tau_n))\} \qquad \qquad (1)$$ is dense below $p"$.
On page 197 (VII, $\S3$), he then says that when we relativize $(1)$ to $M$ (c.t.m. of $\sf{ZFC}$), we get $$``\{r \leq p : \exists \sigma \in M^{\mathbb{P}}(r \Vdash^* \phi(\sigma))^M\} \ \text{is dense below $p$}."$$ I don't understand why when relativized to $M$, we get $r \leq p$? Does this follow from transitivity of $M$?

It has nothing to do with relativization to $M$. The original definition could have had $r\le p$ too. A set $X\subseteq \mathbb P$ is dense below $p$ if and only if $\{q\in X: q\le p\}$ is dense below $p$. (Or in other words, it does follow from transitivity... but transitivity of $\le$.)

Thanks, as always, for your willingness to engage =). That makes sense, sorry, I am probably too tired to think, and had to outsource this. :/
